# Balloon tips on controls in Delphi 7 with no XP manifest

Tags: delphi, tooltip, delphi-7

We are using the code here http://www.delphitricks.com/source-code/forms/show_balloon_tooltips_in_my_delphi_program.html to invoke a balloon tip on an TEdit control.

The problem is that the tip only appears if the mouse pointer is over the control, hence code on the OnEnter or OnChange that should show the tip isn't firing. We assume that the code we are using is similar to standard hints that only appear while the mouse is over the control, but we need it to appear wherever the mouse currently is.

FYI, this is so we can emulate what happens when you go into a TEdit control where a password is being entered, and the warning appears if the caps lock is turned on. Sadly we can't use the xpmanifest to do this automatically.

How can we get the tip to be shown if the mouse isn't over it?

Thanks for your help as always.

Answer (score 0):

Coincidentally I've just wanted to do something very similar and have ended up creating my own class derived from <s>TShape</s> <s>TGraphicControl</s> TCustomPanel (using TCustomPanel since TGraphicControl can never have it's z-order above any other windowed control) but using some of the `Paint` code from TShape, overriding the `Paint` method (adding a call to `Canvas.TextOut`) and adding a Text property and various other things, i.e. click on the toolip and it closes.

Usage (where edt1 is an edit control to attach the tooltip):

```
ToolTip:=TlbrToolTip.Create(edt1);
ToolTip.Parent:=edt.Parent;
ToolTip.Text:='This is the tooltip text';
```

Then add `ToolTip.Show` in whatever Edit events you require, `Tooltip.Hide` hides it.

I've added a shown property, which I use to indicate that the tooltip has been shown at somepoint, and then add a `Tooltip.Reset` (which hides the tip and sets `Shown` to false) call to the OnExit event of the relevant control. This way if the user clicks on the tooltip to hide it I can control it so that the tip doesn't pop back up unless the control has lost focus. This isn't an all singing and dancing control, but it's fine my purpose and maybe useful for someone else.

```
type TlbrToolTip = class (TCustomPanel)
    private
      fOwner: TControl;
      fPen: TPen;
      fBrush: TBrush;
      fText: String;
      fShown: Boolean;
      procedure SetText(const Value: String);
    protected
      procedure Paint; override;
      procedure PerformClick(Sender: TObject);
    public
      constructor Create(aOwner: TComponent); override;
      destructor Destroy; override;
      property Shown: Boolean read fShown; //If true then at some point the tooltip has been shown.
    published
      procedure StyleChanged(Sender: TObject);
      procedure Show;
      procedure Hide;
      procedure Reset(Sender: TObject); //Sets shown to false.
      property Text: String read fText write SetText;
      property OnClick;
    end;

implementation

{ TlbrToolTip }

procedure TlbrToolTip.PerformClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Visible:=False;
end;

constructor TlbrToolTip.Create(aOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  visible:=false;
  ControlStyle := ControlStyle + [csReplicatable, csNoDesignVisible];
  fOwner:=(aOwner as TControl);
  Width := 65;
  Height := 30;
  FPen := TPen.Create;
  FPen.OnChange := StyleChanged;
  FBrush := TBrush.Create;
  FBrush.Color:=clInfoBk;
  FBrush.OnChange := StyleChanged;
  OnClick:=PerformClick;
end;

destructor TlbrToolTip.Destroy;
begin
  FPen.Free;
  FBrush.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TlbrToolTip.Hide;
begin
  visible:=False;
end;

procedure TlbrToolTip.Paint;
var
  X, Y, W, H, S, tw, th: Integer;
begin
  with Canvas do
  begin
    Pen := FPen;
    Brush := FBrush;
    X := Pen.Width div 2;
    Y := X;
    W := Width - Pen.Width + 1;
    H := Height - Pen.Width + 1;
    if Pen.Width = 0 then
    begin
      Dec(W);
      Dec(H);
    end;
    if W < H then S := W else S := H;
    RoundRect(X, Y, X + W, Y + H, S div 4, S div 4);
    th:=TextHeight(fText);
    tw:=TextWidth(fText);
    TextOut((Self.width-tw) div 2,(Self.Height-th) div 2,fText);
  end;
end;

procedure TlbrToolTip.Reset(Sender: TObject);
begin
  visible:=False;
  fShown:=False;
end;

procedure TlbrToolTip.SetText(const Value: String);
begin
  fText := Value;
  Width:=Max(65,6+canvas.TextWidth(fText));
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TlbrToolTip.Show;
var
  l,t: integer;
begin
  if not fShown and not (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
    begin
    l:=fOwner.Left;
    t:=fOwner.Top+fOwner.Height+2;
    if (l+self.Width>fOwner.Parent.ClientWidth) then
      l:=fOwner.Parent.ClientWidth-self.Width-(fOwner.Width-fOwner.ClientWidth);
    if (t+self.Height>fOwner.Parent.ClientHeight) then
      t:=fOwner.Top-self.Height-2;
    Left:=l;
    Top:=t;
    BringToFront;
    Visible:=true;
    end;
  fShown:=True;
end;

procedure TlbrToolTip.StyleChanged(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Invalidate;
end;
```